# Need comscore.swc for integrating Comscore in Flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, comscore

Where can I download comscore.swc file for integrating Comscore in Flex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did a Google search and found this in ~30 seconds:

- [comScore - Tag Specific Document](http://www.cmf-fmc.ca/documents/files/programs/dm-reporting/comscore/FlashFlexAIR-Application-Measurement.pdf)

Couple paragraphs in under **requirements** says:

> - comScore SDK's `comscore.swc`
>     This is the comScore Flash/Flex(AIR) app tagging SDK. *Please request it to your
>     comScore Client Service representative*.

That suggests you need to ask your Client Service rep at comScore for the `.swc` (it is not available for download from the internet).

Comment: Thanx Marty Wallace, I missed that line in a hurry.